# Not able to submit field value with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know that there was a similar questions to this, but I tried everything and nothing seems to work. I'm not that good with ajax thats why i posted this question.

```
$("#buttons_holder").find("#add_users").click(function() {
    var ob = document.getElementById('all_users[]');
    var selected = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < ob.options.length; i++) {
        if (ob.options[i].selected) {
            selected.push(ob.options[i].value);
        }// if
    }// for
    var selected_users = selected;
    var link = $("#buttons_holder").find("#add_users").attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          s : selected_users
        },
        'success': function(data){
            alert ('succes');
        },
        'error' : function(data) {
            alert ('fail');
        }
    });
});
```

And I always get fail alerted. I try to alert all parametes(selected_users, link) before function and everything seems ok. Can anyone tell me what could be a problem? Thanks you all very much for your answers.

EDIT: Here's my HTML Code:

```
<div class="main_content">
      <div id="users_holder">
<div class="div_grids">
    <div class="inline_wrapper">
      <h4>Users that belong to selected company:</h4>
        <label for="company_users">
            <select multiple="" name="company_users[]" id="company_users[]">
                                        <option value="1">admin@sms.com</option>
                                        <option value="3">b@bba.com</option>
                                        <option value="5">dfsdf@dmfkdmf.com</option>
                                </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:2%; margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%" id="buttons_holder" class="inline_wrapper">
        <div class="common_add_button">
             <a id="remove_users" name="remove_users" href="http://localhost/cake/crawler/companies/1/manage-agents/remove"> &gt;&gt; </a>
        </div>

        <div class="common_add_button">
            <a id="add_users" name="add_users" href="http://localhost/cake/crawler/companies/1/manage-agents/add"> &lt;&lt; </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline_wrapper">
        <h4>All users:</h4>
            <label for="all_users">
                <select multiple="" name="all_users[]" id="all_users[]">
                                                <option value="4">11111@qweqwe.com</option>
                                        </select>
            </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

SOLUTION:

```
$("#buttons_holder").find("#add_users").click(function() {

    var selected_users = $('#all_users option:selected').map(function() {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    var link = '{$add_users_link}';
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'new_users' : selected_users
        },
        'success': function(data) {
            App.Messages.showOkFlashMessage(data);
        },
        'error': function(data) {
            App.Messages.showErrorFlashMessage(data.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: check the request status using the browser developer tools network tab

Comment: What is value in selected_users ?

Comment: Can u post your HTML and also did u check for the errors in the console?

Comment: on a side note the selected users logic can be rewritten as `var selected_users = $('#all_users\\[\\] option:selected').map(function () {
        return this.value
    }).get();`

Comment: I have added logging code for you, what are the outputs?

Comment: Suggestion: use console.log() and not alert() ;)

Comment: It would help if you add your html example

Comment: Yes, all add HTML in a moment.

Comment: it has to be a server error or a parse error ... what is the response status and the response body

Comment: @ArunPJohny first it was a parse error. I fix it. Also thanks for previous comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

When I use Ajax and arrays, I always pass the data as string and deserialize on the server.
Since the parameters seem to be ok to you, maybe you can try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { s : JSON.stringify(selected_users) },
    'success': function(data) { alert ('success'); },
    'error': function(data) { alert ('fail'); }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

@Marko Vasic Ajax require Json format data so you have to send data in json format like
 JSON.stringify({ s: selected_users })

```
var selected_users = selected;
var link = $("#buttons_holder").find("#add_users").attr('href');
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: 'POST',
    data: 
     JSON.stringify({ s: selected_users }),

    'success': function(data){
        alert ('succes');
    },
    'error' : function(data) {
        alert ('fail');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: This is nonsense. AJAX doesn't *require* JSON, it is just an option.

Comment: @MalkiatSingh- Paaji jab normal se ho sakta hai to JSON ko kaha ghused ahe ho??

Comment: @Carnio and Rony I have seen in the solution updated above data:{'new_users' : selected_users }. This is looks like a json. If we can write json.Stringify(s,selected_users). This will make json autonatically.